# UITableView not updating when tableView.reloadData() is called, what is causing this problem?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, asynchronous, uisearchbar

I have a table view that initially starts empty. I am trying to update it once an asynchronous method is called `Networking().fetchRecipies(ingredients: searchText)`. However, after this method is called, the `recipieTableView` remains unpopulated. What is causeing this error? Below is the code I am running that should be run everytime the text in the text field changes. I know this is working because I am also printing the results of the API call

```
@IBOutlet weak var recipieTableView: UITableView!
var recipies = LocalData.recipies.recipieList
var filteredRecipies = [Recipie]()
    
    
override func viewDidLoad() {
    filteredRecipies = recipies
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
     Networking().fetchRecipies(ingredients: searchText)
     self.recipieTableView.reloadData()
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
         self.recipieTableView.reloadData()
         self.recipieTableView.beginUpdates()
         self.recipieTableView.endUpdates()
     }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you haven’t set the `dataSource` for the table view? Also, you would appear to be trying to reload the table view immediately after calling `fetchRecipies`, but is that an asynchronous method? Does it perform a network request? If so, you should reload the table after the request is done. We can’t comment without more info about what `fetchRecipies` is doing...

Answer (score 0):

> However, after this method is called, the recipieTableView remains unpopulated. What is causeing this error

What's causing the error is that when you say "after" you should actually be saying "before"! Your code does not run in the order it is written. It runs in this order:

```
 Networking().fetchRecipies(ingredients: searchText) // 2
 self.recipieTableView.reloadData() // 1...
 // ...
```

In other words, all your calls to `reloadData` are happening *before* you fetch the recipes.

You need to write `fetchRecipes` such that *it* reloads the table view after the fetching has finished.

Answer (score 0):

You say the method `Networking().fetchRecipies(ingredients:)` is called asynchronously, which basically means your code steps into another thread and simultaneously continues to execute to the end of the method your asynchronous function was called from.

So the line `self.recipieTableView.reloadData()` is called when your data is not yet populated.

After that you call `DispatchQueue.main.async` which is also unnecessary. Since you're already on the main thread (because that's the convention for `searchBar(_:textDidChange:)`, as for the most of UIKit methods), the only thing your method does is runs the contents of the dispatched block of code some time later (but chances are still much sooner before your fetch request completes).

Read more on how concurrency works on iOS in the official [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW1). If you're a beginner, it would be just enough to understand the difference between serial and concurrent queues and `sync` and `async` dispatches.

Back to your problem. I suggest that you examine the API of your `Networking` class and check if there's any way to notify you when your data has been actually fetched. Most iOS APIs provide a completion block that is executed with your newly fetched data passed as an argument. For example, it could look like the following:

```
Networking().fetchRecipies(ingredients: searchText, completion: { fetchedIngredients in 
   // ... update your data source array
   // reload table view
})
```

Call `tableView.updateData()` directly from inside such a block if it's called on the main queue, or wrap it inside `DispatchQueue.main.async { }` if your completion block is invoked from a background queue (refer to the API to find it out).

And, most important, don't forget to update your array (I believe it's either `recipies` or `filteredRecipies`) which serves as the source for your table's data BEFORE you call `updateData()`.